# Gaussian Curve Fitting - Parameter Estimation

Tags: statistics, estimation

I was redirected here because someone in SO pointed out this is more of a math question than a programming question:

I have to fit a Gaussian curve to a noisy set of data and then take it's FWHM for a certain application. I used MATLAB to demo the concept, and curve fitting in MATLAB is extremely easy.

However, I eventually have to translate the code into Java/Android. I tried looking for libraries in Android that would help me fit a Gaussian curve to data set, but I couldn't find anything. Consequently, I started trying to learn all the math involved so I could do it manually.

My question: How do I go about estimating the three parameters (center, width, height) for a single-term gaussian model? I tried looking into the Expectation-Maximization algorithm but that went way over my head.

In general, I assume it would have something to do with error minimization? I'm just having trouble figuring out the step-by-step method of fitting a gaussian curve to my data.

Thanks for the help! Alec

EDIT:

One of the things I tried already involved taking the natural log of my data, fitting a parabola to the result using LSQR, and then transforming back. However, the results I'm getting aren't accurate, probably because this method is biased in some way or another.

If you don't know how to do parameter estimation, do you have any other suggestions of fitting a curve to my data? (Remember, it has to be manual since Android seems to be fairly limited on it's statistics libraries)

Comment: Not a full answer: A Gaussian distribution is parametrized only by its mean and variance. So if you calculate the sample mean and variance of your data, that alone should be enough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters Also, can you mention what form your data is in; is it a set of numbers that are supposed to be samples from a normal distribution?

Comment: I heard that my sample's mean and variance wouldn't give me the "curve-of-best-fit" considering how noisy my data is. And my data is a set of light intensity readings, and I'm trying to fit a normal distribution to it.

Comment: If you want the mean and variance, you usually use maximum likelihood. That is, set up the log-likelihood function and use a numerical maximizer/minimizer to find the parameter estimates.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail? Statistics isn't exactly my strong suit. I remember reading about log-likelihood functions and maximization/minimization, but like I said, it went WAY over my head with all the technical symbology and jargon.

Comment: Can you answer my second question? I am confused whether you want to fit a curve through some given points $(x_k,y_k)$ and think that the curve should be Gaussian ($y = c e^{-(x-a)^2/b}$), or whether you have some numbers $\{x_k\}$ sampled from normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and want to find their distribution. The two possible questions are quite different.

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: I see. Then what I said earlier is irrelevant. You need what's called "nonlinear regression" (or "nonlinear least squares"). In R this is the function nls (check out its documentation). I don't know if there's an existing Android library out there. If you really need to implement this yourself, start with the gradient descent method because it is the easiest to understand. If I understand you correctly, you need to minimize the function $f(a,b,c) = \sum_k (y_k - c e^{-(x_k-a)^2/b})^2$ with respect to $a$, $b$, and $c$. For questions about numerical optimization there is also scicomp.SE.

Comment: "the results I'm getting aren't accurate": can you explain or show a plot ? If there are outlier data points, you may have to resort to robust fitting techniques (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression).

Comment: since it is only Gaussians there must be a way to estimate the centers at least using a method other than `nls`, which is slow.

Answer (score 3):

There is a straightforward method (no need for initial guess, no iterrative process). The program is short and very easy to write : Listing on page 7 in this paper :
http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

Note: The algorithm on page 7 is only the part giving the two main parameters (center, width). Then, computing the third parameter (amplitude), requires only a linear regression.

LATTER ADDITION (answer to dashesy's request) :

[image]

Numerical example (screen copy) :

[image]

Details of computation :

[image]

Comment: Is it fitting data to Gaussian; like what the question is about and is usually solved with `nls`? If yes can you please elaborate the method here, because it is in French. I think the method is to multiply by `t` and integrate, like taking moments, right?

Comment: @ dashesy : see the addition to my first answer. Presently, there is no available translation of the document.

Comment: thanks, looking up answers here is easier than reading papers anyways, condensed and to the point, very useful and interesting method

Comment: had some problems to get things together with the french paper (due to the different definition of the parameters b and c). I guess there is a minus sign missing in the exponent in the first line of this answer (Fitting of y=...). Additionally i think that, when using the parameters as defined in the paper, sigma has to be calculated as sigma = sqrt(-1.0 / B)

Comment: @ Janosch : You are right, they are several typo in the section "Latter addition", some minus are missing. I will fix this as soon as possible. No typo in the section "numerical example", the minus are at correct places. Thank you very much and my congratulations for your thorough inspection.

Comment: Does it work for multiple Gaussians in one data set?

Comment: The above numerical process is strictly made for the fitting of one Gaussian function (3 adjustable parameters). If case of two Gaussians, the function to be fitted includes 6 adjustable parameters which is a lot. With this method of regression and integral equation, the numerical process would requires multiple integrals. The deviations due to numerical integrations would certainly become too large to obtain a sufficiently accurate result.