# Analytic curve fit: one Gauss curve fitting a bimodal model

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, maximum-likelihood

**Problem:**

I have a completely **noise-free** model, ytot, which is the sum of two perfect Gaussian curves evaluted at points $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ with $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$y_0(x_i)= A_0  e^{ - \frac{(x_i-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_0^2} } $$
$$y_1(x_i) = A_1 e^{ - \frac{(x_i-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} } $$
$$ y(x_i) = y_0(x_i) + y_1(x_i)$$

I need to fit them via least sqaures curve fit as a **single** Gauss curve. But rather than numerical fitting, I want to analytically find the minimum of this least squares function, using that I have no noise and know the shape of y0, y1, and ytot:

$$\min \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( A e^{ - \frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } - y_\mathrm{tot} \right)^2 \right]$$

**Question:**

As I know the true ytot (completely noise-free): is there any analytical solution that represents what a least sqaures optimizer does in this case? E.g. analytically solving a Jacobian or gradient for this case?

**More info:**

The least sqaures curve fit can be done e.g. in Python using scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). However, I have to perform this fit millions of times for different parameters, making this a bottleneck to my code.

Note: I can NOT use the statistical point of view here (e.g. mu=p*mu0+(1-p)*mu1 and so on). Both approaches lead to very similar solutions if mu0~mu1 and std0~std1, but differ systematically with increasing bimodularity.

I have checked out this post:
[Gaussian Curve Fitting - Parameter Estimation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441422/gaussian-curve-fitting-parameter-estimation).
However, it differed systematically from the results of scipy.optimize.curve_fit().

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Would you elaborate as to why you'd want a unimodal fit to a known bimodal curve?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution after two days of thinking and linear algebra. I hope this will be useful to others in the future.

Instead of fitting a Gaussian to y, one can fit a parabola to log(y). A parabolic least squares problem can be easily solved via linear algebra, see e.g. in this [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vXgizn0Zz5VM_mTEfrRqwydfCyn0OY5DNlkieFLRU68/edit) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwZYSTQs-Hk).

This is prone to outliers on the wings, so one has to use a [weighted least square model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares). I used weights = $y^2$.

Of course, right after figuring it out, I found this very clear [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252062037_A_Simple_Algorithm_for_Fitting_a_Gaussian_Function_DSP_Tips_and_Tricks) that outlines exactly the same approach. Please see the paper for the detailed solution.